# No puedo hacer un signup en AngularFire

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-auth

Estoy tratando de aprender firebase angular. Quiero hacer un simple pagina para un signup pero por alguna razon no me deja

Cuando me fijo en firebase no se agregan los usuarios y la alerta que puse que se muestre no se muestra.

Tambien tengo una autenticacion con google pero esa funciona sin problema y en firebase aparece.

Este es mi service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { auth } from 'firebase';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
    constructor(private xauth: AngularFireAuth) { }

    signup(email, pass){
        return this.xauth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).then(()=>{
        alert('registro completado');
    });
```

Este es mi signup.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/servicios/auth.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-registro',
    templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css']
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public auth: AuthService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }
}
```

Este es mi signup.component.html:

```
<h3 class = "text-center">Signup</h3>

<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" #user>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" #pass>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="auth.registro(user, pass)">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

Este es mi app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { AngularFireModule} from '@angular/fire';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { SignupComponent } from './componentes/signup/signup.component';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    RegistroComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule, AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireAuthModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:D hay algunas cosas que pueden dar error en el código te aconsejaría que en vez de obtener el resultado de los inputs mediante  #Id lo hicieras mediante un NgModel o un formBuilder para tenerlo todo mas controlado y que toda la información pase por el archivo signup.component.ts para poder hacer validaciones etc. 
En cuanto a tu problema creo que se podría resolverse así:

En tu service:

```
public signup(email, pass){
   return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
     this.firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
     .then(res => {
       resolve(res);
     }, err => reject(err))
   })
 }
```

En signup.component.ts:

```
  public register(email, pass){
  this.authService.signup(email,pass)
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    this.errorMessage = "";
    this.successMessage = "Your account has been created";
  }, err => {
    console.log(err);
    this.errorMessage = err.message;
    this.successMessage = "";
  })
}
```

En signup.component.html :

```
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="this.register(user, pass)"
```